# Remove caption on product image PDP

Tags: magento2.2.4

*Magento 2.2.4,*

**How to remove the caption which is available on the image?. Is there any configuration available to disable it.**

[image]

Comment: So it's not just me. I thought I edited view.xml while half asleep.

Answer (score 3):

Magento currently has a bug where the default values of the carousel aren't handled properly. You can manually edit a core file `(vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml)` like this:
replace

```
"options": {
"nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/nav") ?>",
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/loop"))): ?>
    "loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/loop") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"))): ?>
    "keyboard": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/arrows"))): ?>
    "arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/arrows") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"))): ?>
    "allowfullscreen": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/caption"))): ?>
    "showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/caption") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"width": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width') ?>",
"thumbwidth": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width') ?>",
<?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width')): ?>
    "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/thumbmargin"))): ?>
    "thumbmargin": <?= /* @noEscape */ (int)$block->getVar("gallery/thumbmargin"); ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width')): ?>
    "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration")): ?>
    "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect") ?>",
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"))): ?>
    "navarrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navtype") ?>",
"navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navdir") ?>"
},
"fullscreen": {
"nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav") ?>",
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop")): ?>
    "loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir") ?>",
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/navarrows")): ?>
    "navarrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navarrows") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navtype") ?>",
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows")): ?>
    "arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")): ?>
    "showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration")): ?>
    "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect") ?>"
},
```

**with**

```
"options": {
"nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/nav") ?>",
"loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/loop") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"keyboard": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/arrows") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"allowfullscreen": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/caption") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"width": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width') ?>",
"thumbwidth": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width') ?>",
<?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width')): ?>
    "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/thumbmargin"))): ?>
    "thumbmargin": <?= /* @noEscape */ (int)$block->getVar("gallery/thumbmargin"); ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width')): ?>
    "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration")): ?>
    "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect") ?>",
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>
"navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navtype") ?>",
"navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navdir") ?>"
},
"fullscreen": {
"nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav") ?>",
"loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir") ?>",
"navarrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navarrows") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navtype") ?>",
"arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
"showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption") ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
<?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration")): ?>
    "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration") ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
"transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect") ?>"
},
```

Or create a template which overrides the Magento template and place the changes in that file.

There is a pull request in progress for this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/15546

For now you can fix it as follows:

```
<?php // FIX FOR https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/15546
if (($block->getVar("gallery/caption"))!==null): ?>
    "showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption")? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If you could kindly elaborate on where to place that code, that would make your answer super helpful. Appreciated.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: line 202

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml

```
<var name="caption">true</var>
```

to

```
<var name="caption">false</var>
```

and cache flush

Comment: It has already been set as false <var name="caption">false</var>

Comment: Also, I have checked changing the showcaption: true, to false lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js which has disable the caption on image....But is that a right solution?

Comment: @Haritha  I confirm. This did not work for me either. I already had them (two caption values) set to False. One for the normal image, one for the Full-Screen mode. I set it to true/false, removed cache still caption shows.

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem in **showCaption**

need add also **showcaption**

in JavaScript exist bug with option showcaption

showCaption vs showcaption - these different param

so, just override

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

copy row with **showCaption**, and add row with **showcaption**

And need add settings to view.xml

Answer (score 0):

this might be a fotorama.js issue and the best and easiest way to remove it is through your Theme's Custom Style (CSS). Usually it is available on your admin theme panel settings

put this to your custom css:

```
.fotorama__caption {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

then save
then cache:flush then check if it is removed already