# After updating to Magento 2.2.6 On Product Page Caption text coming default

Tags: magento2.2.6

After updating to magento 2.2.6 on product detail page a caption text comes.
Will anyone let me know the file name of this caption text in directory because I don't want this text.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/l2il8n

Comment: This is coming from image label from admin, if there is no image label then product name will show.

Comment: I know this but want to remove from code not using css.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/231031) will help you

Comment: You can remove it using css if you don't need it, because it is the simplest way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove caption on product image PDP](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231021/remove-caption-on-product-image-pdp)